# CMD is not running use together with ENTRYPOINT

Tags: docker, dockerfile, podman

I try to run a container with `ENTRYPOINT /sbin/init` to allow me to run `systemctl` command.
After that I use `CMD sh-exports.sh` to execute the some command from the script.

*Dockerfile*

```sh
FROM registry.redhat.io/ubi8/ubi-init

ADD sh-exports.sh /
ARG S3FS_VERSION=v1.86
ARG MNT_POINT=/var/s3fs
ENV MNT_POINT=${MNT_POINT}
RUN yum install somepackages -y && mkdir -p "$MNT_POINT" && chmod 755 "$MNT_POINT" && chmod 777 /sh-exports.sh 

ENTRYPOINT [ "/sbin/init", "$@" ]
CMD "/sh-exports.sh"
```

*sh-exports.sh*

```sh
#!/bin/bash    

echo $EXPORTS > /etc/exports
systemctl restart some.services

sleep infinity
```

The script `sh-exports.sh` is not executed.
I can actually login to the container and simply run `sh /sh-exports.sh` and the script can run just fine.

So, is there anyway to allow me to use `ENTRYPOINT /sbin/init` and then any command at the `CMD`?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is by design, and the way to run your command is to have an entrypoint that is able to receive the command as an argument.

Your actual trial is the opposite of what is commonly done, you usually have a command passed to an entrypoint and this command is the one *"keeping the container alive"*.

So, the *Dockerfile* should have those instructions:

```sh
COPY entrypoint.sh entrypoint.sh

CMD ["sleep", "infinity"]
ENTRYPOINT ["entrypoint.sh"]
```

And this *entrypoint.sh* should be:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash  

/sbin/init
echo $EXPORTS > /etc/exports
systemctl restart some.services

exec "$@"
```

If you want to be able to alter the instruction passed to `systemctl` in the docker command, like

```sh
docker run my-container other-service
```

What you can do instead is

```sh
COPY entrypoint.sh entrypoint.sh

CMD ["some.services"]
ENTRYPOINT ["entrypoint.sh"]
```

And then, the entrypoint will look like:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash  

/sbin/init
echo $EXPORTS > /etc/exports
systemctl restart "$@"

sleep infinity
```

---

The reason for all this is, when using a command in combination with an entrypoint, the command is passed as an argument to the entrypoint, so, the responsibility to execute the command (or not) is actually delegated to the entrypoint.

So there is nothing *"magic"* happening really, it is like you would normally do in a shell script, one script (the entrypoint) receives arguments (the command) and can execute the received arguments as a command, or as part of a command.

This table actually explain the different behaviours:

|  | No ENTRYPOINT | ENTRYPOINT exec_entry p1_entry | ENTRYPOINT [“exec_entry”, “p1_entry”] |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **No CMD** | *error, not allowed* | /bin/sh -c exec_entry p1_entry | exec_entry p1_entry |
| **CMD [“exec_cmd”, “p1_cmd”]** | exec_cmd p1_cmd | /bin/sh -c exec_entry p1_entry | exec_entry p1_entry exec_cmd p1_cmd |
| **CMD [“p1_cmd”, “p2_cmd”]** | p1_cmd p2_cmd | /bin/sh -c exec_entry p1_entry | exec_entry p1_entry p1_cmd p2_cmd |
| **CMD exec_cmd p1_cmd** | /bin/sh -c exec_cmd p1_cmd | /bin/sh -c exec_entry p1_entry | exec_entry p1_entry /bin/sh -c exec_cmd p1_cmd |

<sup>*Source: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-cmd-and-entrypoint-interact*</sup>

Comment: when you say to have this in entrypoint last line  `exec "$@"`, do you mean `ENTRYPOINT ["/sbin/init", "exec", "$@" ]` ?

Comment: Answer updated to make it hopefully clearer.

Comment: I have follow your steps, the script succesfully executed, but the container cannot run `systemctl` command, i think that is because of the pid 1 is now `sleep infinity` instead of `/sbin/init`?