# How to keep a Docker container running for troubleshooting?

Tags: docker

I have a simple Docker container which retrieves some environment variables from the AWS service Parameter Store.

I have a shell script in my ENTRYPOINT which pulls these params and injects them into the environment variables. Problem is, I want to keep the container running so I can check the values of these environment variables.

I am not sure how to keep the container running so I can do that.

This is the **Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:18.15.0-alpine3.17

################
#install aws cli
RUN apk update && apk add --update --no-cache \
    git \
    bash \
    curl \
    openssh \
    python3 \
    py3-pip \
    py-cryptography \
    wget \
    curl

RUN apk --no-cache add --virtual builds-deps build-base python3
RUN pip install --upgrade pip && \
    pip install --upgrade awscli
################

WORKDIR /app

COPY ./env-vars.sh /app/env-vars.sh

ENTRYPOINT /app/env-vars.sh

#this is an attempt to keep the container running
CMD tail -f /dev/null
```

This is the **/app/env-vars.sh** shell script

```
PARAM_PATH="/some/path/" #the results is a list of items like: 

if [[ -n "$PARAM_PATH" ]]; then
  params=$(aws ssm get-parameters-by-path --path "$PARAM_PATH" --region us-east-1 --recursive --query "Parameters[*].{Name:Name,Value:Value}" --output text)

  # Loop through the fetched parameters and export them as environment variables

  echo $params | while read -r name value; do
    # $name example: /some/path/APP_NAME - $value example: someApp
    if [[ -n "$name" && -n "$value" ]]; then
      var_name=$(echo "$name" | awk -F'/' '{print $NF}') # Extract the last part of the parameter name
      export "$var_name"="$value"
    fi
  done
fi
```

Any input will help.

Thanks!

Comment: An entrypoint needs to actually _invoke_ your CMD. It's not a thing that runs _before_ the CMD, it's a thing _responsible for running_ the CMD.

Comment: Also, your entrypoint is buggy; `echo $params | while read` will never work the way you intend (setting variables that stay assigned after the loop exits) for the reasons given in https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024, and also the reasons given in [I just assigned a variable, but `echo $variable` shows something else!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29378566/i-just-assigned-a-variable-but-echo-variable-shows-something-else)

Comment: Also, think about `var_name=${name##*/}` -- all built into the shell.

Comment: You could also just add `env` to the end of your `env-vars.sh` (after/outside the loop!) to dump the variables as they're set before it exits -- but again, you'll need to make the _actual_ last line be something like `exec "$@"` to run the arguments it's passed as a new command so your CMD gets invoked at all.

Comment: (...if I had a dupehammer that applied to this one, there are other questions I would be adding to the duplicate list as well as the above: the aforementioned [I just assigned a variable, but echo $variable shows something else!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29378566), and also [Why are variable values lost after terminating the loop in bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26144029)

Comment: BTW, do you have jq in your container? It supports generating eval-safe escaping of JSON content, so you could use it to directly transform a JSON result into a stream of shell commands you can evaluate.

Comment: (The question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71770022/cmd-is-not-running-use-together-with-entrypoint is _specifically_ using a `sleep infinity` for the reason you are here, thus being not just on-point in the sense of having a technical problem in common with your script and having solutions describing how to solve that problem, but also speaking directly to the titular question).

Comment: Your script doesn't seem to actually be running the command at all; it's running a bunch of `export` commands and then exiting, and since you've set that as the image's `ENTRYPOINT`, that is the only thing the container does.  Is there a main process you expect the container to run?